# validation for 12 hours time with AM/PM using java script in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am trying to validate the time in

```
00:00 to 11:59 ends with AM OR PM
```

I was tring some regex,but not getting succesful to validate time.
My java script function is

```
function verifydata( incoming ) {
var re = (1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)?(?i)(am|pm);
if(incoming.time.value != '' && !incoming.time.value.match(re)) 
{
alert("Invalid time format: " + incoming.time.value);
}
}
```

its not working

I tried this also, not working

```
var re = /^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
```

let me where I am going wrong?

Comment: what's the source of the string?

Comment: string is being entered in textbox by user

Comment: What does `?i` do? (Also, you know `(am|pm)` will only match lower case letters. Right?) Your regex won't match "00:00" because it only allows "0:00".

Comment: @Lee Meador: That is a way of specifying case-insensitive matching in PCRE (the regex library PHP uses); however, JavaScript does not support that.

Comment: @leemeador, not having so much knowledge of regex..just searched and tried a lot of regex....in case of( am|pm ), we can add (AM|PM) also ?

Comment: @pleasestand can you tell me then how to use that in javascript any other method?

Comment: In JavaScript, case insensitive matching is still possible (for the entire regex only) using the `i` flag (after the ending slash). PHP PCRE also supports that.

Comment: i would enforce the limits at input, as well as checking by php

Comment: I like testing my javascript regex here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html where you can try lots of things to see what works.

Comment: @pleasestand ok,if i leave that case sensitivity then?

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
function testTime( time ) {
  var regex = /^([0-1][0-9])\:[0-5][0-9]\s*[ap]m$/i;
  var match = time.match( regex );
  if ( match ) {
    var hour  = parseInt( match[1] );
    if ( !isNaN( hour) && hour <= 11 ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

testTime( '12:00 AM' ); // false  
testTime( '11:59 PM' ); // true  
testTime( '00:00 AM' ); // true  
testTime( '00:00am' ); // true  
testTime( '10:00pm' ); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not support `(?i)`, yet it does support the `i` flag to enable case-insensitive matching for the entire regexp. Also, in regexp literals (as opposed to normal string literals), do not escape the backslash when it is used as a metacharacter:

```
var re = /^(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\s?(am|pm)$/i;
```

Comment: This is the better answer, though a bit inconsistent with the capturing groups... Everything explained with demo: http://regex101.com/r/oB7hJ2

Comment: The original code was already inconsistent yet placed the `\s` in its own unnecessary group. To be consistent, simply add a `?:` after each `(`. Then there would be no capturing groups.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a fan of regular expressions for everything - in particular, I dislike them for number ranges.

Assuming some lateral in how the function is written:

```
 // regex used for "high level" check and extraction
 // matches "hh:mmAM", "hh:mm", "hh:mm PM", etc
 var matches = inp.match(/^(\d\d):(\d\d)\s?(?:AM|PM)?$/)
 if (matches && matches.length == 3) {
   var h = parseInt(matches[1], 10)
   var m = parseInt(matches[2], 10)
   // range checks done in code after getting numeric value
   return h >= 1 && h <= 12 && m >= 0 && m <= 59
 } else {
   return false
 }
```

Comment: not working..nothing happens :(

Comment: @user2608523 In this case "nothing happens" meant "it returned an incorrect value". I've fixed the code which was a bug in the usage of `matches`.

Comment: i am testing it using alert..it is goin in my function but not going in if or else part

Comment: @user2608523 See very latest update. Double fail on my part but [now works](http://jsfiddle.net/ME9PB/). That being said, this doesn't answer the *why doesn't this work* part of the question; I'm merely proposing that regular expressions don't need to be used exclusively. You'll have to use the `/i` modifier or otherwise change `(?AM|PM)` for it to be case-insensitive. Alternatively, if you allow more relaxed input, consider: `inp.match(/^(\d\d?):(\d\d)(?\D|$)/` which doesn't even both to match any trailing AM, pm, a.m. or whatever.

Comment: i am using incoming.time.value.match instead of inp.match, because my value is coming from textbox anemd as time..is that ok with me? or i am doing mistake in that?

Comment: What is incoming.time.value? It should be a string (not null, undefined or anything else). As seen in the fiddle, it works as expected with some given input.